# Is there a way to optimal the layout to minimise the whitespace when using a StaggeredGridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, staggered-gridview

How can I minimise the whitespace in my grid?

In my example grid I have three tiles, but as you can see there is a lot of white space next to tile number 0. This space can be filled with tile number 2 to decrease the total white space.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Text]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      itemCount: payback.keys.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index.isEven) {
          return Container(color: Colors.green, width: 100, height: 100, child: Center(child:Text(index.toString(), textScaleFactor: 4, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)));
        } else {
          return Container(color: Colors.green, width: 200, height: 200, child: Center(child:Text(index.toString(), textScaleFactor: 4, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)));
        }
      },
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
        if (index.isEven) {
          return StaggeredTile.fit(1);
        } else {
          return StaggeredTile.fit(2);
        }
      },
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    );
```